# Module not found error but I have pip installed the module

Tags: python

I have correctly pip installed the module, but I am still getting an error and I am not sure why.

My Code:

21:from Crypto.Cipher import AES

22:from PIL import ImageGrab

23:from win32crypt import CryptUnprotectData

Error is:
File "main.py", line 21, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'

(I am an amateur btw)

Comment: Which "pip" module did you install? Is it [`pycrypto`](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/), [`pycryptodome`](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/) or is it something else? Also are you using the same pip version as python? Have you tried `python -m pip` instead?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I was so sleepy and i forgot to put "py" in front of the "crypto" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, also be aware of where are you running the pip command, sometimes you need to run it in the CMD other times it is OK in the terminal or your IDE.

```
# ️ in a virtual environment or using Python 2
pip install your_package

# ️ for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)
pip3 install your_package

# ️ if you get permissions error
sudo pip3 install your_package

# ️ if you don't have pip in your PATH environment variable
python -m pip install your_package

# ️ for python 3 (could also be pip3.10 depending on your version)
python3 -m pip install your_package
```

Comment: oh and try these with --version after to see the version number installed, kinda proof that it is indeed installed already

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on a chromebook this happens and to my knowledge theres no good workaround

Comment: Can you please provide a citation for this assertion, I couldn't find any information online to support this.

Comment: I had seen it somewhere on this site, let me look and try to find it again

Comment: Please do, because there should be nothing stopping source build on chromebooks (also never mind that this question has dependency on `win32crypt` which implies Windows, which chromebooks are not, thus not exactly relevant to the question here).